# A set $S$ of all the different odd positive integers

Tags: number-theory

> Consider the set $S$ of all the different odd positive integers that are not multiples of $5$ and that are less than $30m$, $m$ being a positive integer. What is the smallest integer $k$ such that in any subset of $k$ integers from $S$ there must be two integers one of which divides the other? Prove your result.

We have $S = \{1,3,7,9,11,\ldots,30m-1\}$ and then if $x \in S$, $x \equiv 1,2,3,4 \pmod{5}$. I am not sure how to show divisibility between two integers in the set, but I think looking at the residues will help.

Comment: Are you familiar with the similar problem with "positive integers" instead of "odd positive integers" and without any "multiples of $5$" restriction?  If not, you probably want to think about that first, I imagine it's a simpler case.

Comment: No, in the simplified version you need to choose about half of the integers before one of them divides another.  You definitely should think about how to prove that first, if you aren't familiar with it.

Comment: @ErickWong How do we do it in the simplified case?

Comment: A set of integers where none divides another is called a "primitive set", and we're basically looking for the largest primitive set.  The standard approach in the simple case is to partition the integers according to the largest odd integer dividing that divides each one (so $7,14,28$ are all together).  A primitive set contains $\le 1$ number from each partition, giving an upper bound of about half the integers.  This has to be matched with a lower bound, which we get by taking the largest half of the integers up to $n$.

Comment: @ErickWong I am getting $k \geq \pi(30m)$.

Comment: Just blindly applying the exact same lower bound set as my example (after taking intersections) gives a much stronger bound than $\pi(30m)$.  You really should be looking for a linear-sized set, not $o(m)$.  Notice how similar Aravind's solution is to the model case!

Answer (score 1):

The smallest such $k$ is $8m+1$.

The set of numbers not divisible by 5 in $\{10m+1,10m+3,\ldots,30m-1\}$ is tight: it has size $8m$ and one number cannot divide the other because the ratio of any two numbers is less than 3.

Consider any set $A$ of $8m+1$ numbers in $S$ and write them as $3^kt$, where $t$ is not divisible by 3. Then the maximum number of different values that $t$ can take is the maximum number of integers in $S$ that are not divisible by 3, which is $8m$. Thus two of the numbers in $A$ must be $3^{k_1}t$ and $3^{k_2}t$ and the smaller one divides the larger.